# Silverlight: Sterling Throws Exception

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, isolatedstorage, sterling-db

I have a Sterling Service

```
public sealed class SterlingService : IApplicationService, IApplicationLifetimeAware, IDisposable
{
    private SterlingEngine _engine;
    private static readonly ISterlingDriver _driver = new IsolatedStorageDriver();

    public static SterlingService Current { get; private set; }
    public ISterlingDatabaseInstance Database { get; private set; }

    public static void StartUpDatabase()
    {
        Current.Database = Current._engine.SterlingDatabase.RegisterDatabase<LocalDB>(_driver);
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

And My LocalDB Class where I have the table definitions is:

```
public class LocalDB : BaseDatabaseInstance
{


    protected override List<ITableDefinition> RegisterTables()
    {
        return new List<ITableDefinition>()
          {
             CreateTableDefinition<ContactData, Guid>(k => k.UID.Value)
             .WithIndex<ContactData, int, Guid>("CustomerId", t => t.CustomerId.Value),


              CreateTableDefinition<ContactDetailData, Guid>(k => k.ContactData.UID.Value)
             .WithIndex<ContactDetailData, int, Guid>("CustomerId", t => t.ContactData.CustomerId.Value),
             ....
          };
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when I get the data from storage. 
Save works fine but when I fetch I get "Invalid cast operation exception from String to Guid".

```
    public static List<ContactData> GetContactListFromLocalDB(int customerId)
    {
        var data = (from k in SterlingService.Current.Database.Query<ContactData, int, Guid>("CustomerId")
                    where k.LazyValue != null && k.Index == customerId
                    select k.LazyValue.Value);
        return data.ToList<ContactData>();  (**HERE I GET THE EXCEPTION**)
    }
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a problem with you using the name `CustomerId` for more than one index.

Try changing the names of your indexes from `CustomerId` to something like `ContactData_CustomerId` and `ContactDetailData_CustomerId` (and similarly for any other indexes you haven't shown us).

I can't find anything in the Sterling documentation that suggests that names must be unique.  Nonetheless, when I used Sterling, I gave all my indexes different names and I didn't have any such problems.

(As an aside, it might also be a good idea to move all your index names into string constants somewhere.  That should help to avoid mistyping them, and you should also get IntelliSense support for them.)

Answer (score 0):

http://sterling.codeplex.com/workitem/14343